# Fetch - Consumo de XML - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch

Tengo el sgte inconveniente, estoy intentando consumir una Web Api a traves de JavaScript con Fetch mas no logro dar con el detalle, la respuesta viene en formato XML. Mi codigo es el sgte:

```js
let myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://ws.widetech.com.co");  

  url = 'http://ws.widetech.com.co/wsHistoryGetByPlate.asmx/HistoyDataLastLocationByUser?sLogin=xxxx&sPassword=xxxx';

  let options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: myHeaders,
    mode: 'no-cors',
    cache: 'default'
  };

  fetch(url, options)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    //.then(response => response.text())
    //.then(str => (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
    //.then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Mas me arroja el sgte mensaje

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://ws.widetech.com.co/wsHistoryGetByPlate.asmx/HistoyDataLastLocationByUser?sLogin=xxxx&sPassword=xxxx with MIME type text/xml. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

A pesar q' en la cabecera tengo

> myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://ws.widetech.com.co");

coloco la url directa en el navegador y me devuelve el resultado normalmente

[image: Get introduciendo la url directo en el navegador]

He probado de varias maneras pero nada q doy con el chiste

Si alguien tiene alguna idea, les agradeceria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los encabezados de respuesta se establecen en el servidor (http://ws.widetech.com.co).

Necesitas agregar `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` en `Content-Type` del lado del servidor. Para más información puedes revisar [corb-for-developers](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers)

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias por tu respuesta.Estuve leyendo sobre el tema y efectivamente por parte del servidor no tienen habilitados este tipo de respuesta. El consumo en este caso como lo estoy haciendo en `c# MVC` lo hice por una opción llamada `referencia de objetos`, esto lo puedes encontrar haciendo click derecho en `Referencias`, alli te aparece la opcion `referencia de objetos` la cual es super util y facilita el consumo de la misma. Si quieren saber mas al respecto pueden consultar este link _(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvTUzB8YnS8&index=9&list=PL8lhy0LOIPBtRj3uEVEj7xrLO9HLnj4qx)_

Answer (score 0):

Perfecto muchas gracias por tu respuesta.Estuve leyendo sobre el tema y efectivamente por parte del servidor no tienen habilitados este tipo de respuesta. El consumo en este caso como lo estoy haciendo en `c# MVC` lo hice por una opción llamada `referencia de objetos`, esto lo puedes encontrar haciendo click derecho en `Referencias`, alli te aparece la opcion `referencia de objetos` la cual es super util y facilita el consumo de la misma. Si quieren saber mas al respecto pueden consultar este link *([https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvTUzB8YnS8&index=9&list=PL8lhy0LOIPBtRj3uEVEj7xrLO9HLnj4qx)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvTUzB8YnS8&index=9&list=PL8lhy0LOIPBtRj3uEVEj7xrLO9HLnj4qx)_)*

[image: Referencia]

Click derecho en Referencia te aparecerá "referencia de Objetos"

Luego colocas la URL a consumir

[image: Dirección de la url a consumir]

Luego das click en ir y listo aceptar. Si quieres saber mas mira el link a youtube q coloque mas arriba.